# Assembly: C++ stack variable addresses different/wrong?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

I don't understand why getting the address of one variable is fine and the other gets me 0xD which then crashes due to writing a value at an invalid address (0xD in `r.thefn(0);`).

This is the output which shows the two variables not having a similar address. [Here is what GDB showed and the assembly output](https://gist.github.com/4048376). My x86 assembly isn't great (I have never written x86 assembly). I don't know if it shows enough information, but if I don't, can you tell me what else is required to debug this? Why is one variable 0xBF8BAF1C and the other is 0xD? C++ and assembly code is below but formatted better in the gist link above.

There is a `static_assert` enforcing String to be a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) which means no nontrival constructors. It is using the default constructor C++ generates. It's also on the stack which means if `new` is overloaded it wouldn't affect it. `&` isn't overloaded, but it also looks correct the first two times the function is called.

What might affect the `r` address? I can see variable `varme`'s address is the same the second and third time it's called, but the third time `r` is magically different.

This compiles and runs properly using Visual C++ (2012 works), g++ 4.6.2, fails on [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) ([Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)) using g++ 3.7, 3.6.3 and [Clang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) 3.0.

```
sanity check 1 0xbf8bb4cc
sanity check 2 0xbf8bb4cc 0xbf8bb538
sanity check 3 0xbf8bb4cc 0xbf8bb538
this 0xbf8bb538
sanity check 1 0xbf8baf1c
sanity check 2 0xbf8baf1c 0xbf8baf40
sanity check 3 0xbf8baf1c 0xbf8baf40
this 0xbf8baf40
sanity check 1 0xbf8baf1c
sanity check 2 0xbf8baf1c 0xd
sanity check 3 0xbf8baf1c 0xd
this 0xd
```

Here is the code: One additional note is there is a `static_assert` on String which enforces that it is a POD which means no non-default constructor. I checked operator `&` isn't overloaded.

```
static int aa=0;
aa++;
int varme;

printf("sanity check 1 %p\n", &varme);
String r;
printf("sanity check 2 %p %p\n", &varme, &r);
//auto v=anotherfn(sz);
printf("sanity check 3 %p %p\n", &varme, &r);
//printf("callingfn=%s,%d %p %p\n", sz,aa, v, &r);
r.thefn(0);
return r;

   ¦0x8084101 <callingfn(char const*)+1> mov %esp,%ebp ¦
   ¦0x8084103 <callingfn(char const*)+3> push %esi ¦
   ¦0x8084104 <callingfn(char const*)+4> sub $0x34,%esp ¦
   ¦0x8084107 <callingfn(char const*)+7> mov 0xc(%ebp),%eax ¦
   ¦0x808410a <callingfn(char const*)+10> mov 0x8(%ebp),%ecx ¦
   ¦0x808410d <callingfn(char const*)+13> mov %eax,-0x8(%ebp) ¦
   ¦0x8084110 <callingfn(char const*)+16> mov 0x81bc894,%eax ¦
   ¦0x8084115 <callingfn(char const*)+21> lea 0x1(%eax),%eax ¦
   ¦0x8084118 <callingfn(char const*)+24> mov %eax,0x81bc894 ¦
   ¦0x808411d <callingfn(char const*)+29> lea -0xc(%ebp),%eax ¦
   ¦0x8084120 <callingfn(char const*)+32> mov %esp,%edx ¦
   ¦0x8084122 <callingfn(char const*)+34> mov %eax,0x4(%edx) ¦
   ¦0x8084125 <callingfn(char const*)+37> movl $0x812ee78,(%edx) ¦
   ¦0x808412b <callingfn(char const*)+43> mov %ecx,-0x10(%ebp) ¦
   ¦0x808412e <callingfn(char const*)+46> mov %eax,-0x14(%ebp) ¦
   ¦0x8084131 <callingfn(char const*)+49> call 0x8049a90 <printf@plt> ¦
   ¦0x8084136 <callingfn(char const*)+54> mov %esp,%ecx ¦
   ¦0x8084138 <callingfn(char const*)+56> mov -0x10(%ebp),%edx ¦
   ¦0x808413b <callingfn(char const*)+59> mov %edx,0x8(%ecx) ¦
   ¦0x808413e <callingfn(char const*)+62> mov -0x14(%ebp),%esi ¦
   ¦0x8084141 <callingfn(char const*)+65> mov %esi,0x4(%ecx) ¦
   ¦0x8084144 <callingfn(char const*)+68> movl $0x812ee8b,(%ecx) ¦
   ¦0x808414a <callingfn(char const*)+74> mov %eax,-0x18(%ebp) ¦
   ¦0x808414d <callingfn(char const*)+77> call 0x8049a90 <printf@plt> ¦
   ¦0x8084152 <callingfn(char const*)+82> mov %esp,%ecx ¦
   ¦0x8084154 <callingfn(char const*)+84> mov -0x10(%ebp),%edx ¦
   ¦0x8084157 <callingfn(char const*)+87> mov %edx,0x8(%ecx) ¦
   ¦0x808415a <callingfn(char const*)+90> mov -0x14(%ebp),%esi ¦
   ¦0x808415d <callingfn(char const*)+93> mov %esi,0x4(%ecx) ¦
   ¦0x8084160 <callingfn(char const*)+96> movl $0x812eea1,(%ecx) ¦
   ¦0x8084166 <callingfn(char const*)+102> mov %eax,-0x1c(%ebp) ¦
   ¦0x8084169 <callingfn(char const*)+105> call 0x8049a90 <printf@plt> ¦
                                                                               ¦
   ¦0x8084169 <callingfn(char const*)+105> call 0x8049a90 <printf@plt> ¦
   ¦0x808416e <callingfn(char const*)+110> mov %esp,%ecx ¦
   ¦0x8084170 <callingfn(char const*)+112> mov -0x10(%ebp),%edx ¦
   ¦0x8084173 <callingfn(char const*)+115> mov %edx,(%ecx) ¦
   ¦0x8084175 <callingfn(char const*)+117> movl $0x0,0x4(%ecx) ¦
   ¦0x808417c <callingfn(char const*)+124> mov %eax,-0x20(%ebp) ¦
   ¦0x808417f <callingfn(char const*)+127> call 0x8056d00 <SomeClass<blah>::thefn(blah*)> ¦
  >¦0x8084184 <callingfn(char const*)+132> add $0x34,%esp ¦
   ¦0x8084187 <callingfn(char const*)+135> pop %esi ¦
   ¦0x8084188 <callingfn(char const*)+136> pop %ebp ¦
   ¦0x8084189 <callingfn(char const*)+137> ret $0x4 ¦
   ¦0x808418c nopl 0x0(%eax)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are the stack addresses different/wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316371/why-are-the-stack-addresses-different-wrong)

Comment: Can you put more code please?

Comment: @Nick: Isnt there enough? What else do you need to check why 0xd is listed in printf?

Comment: @acidzombie24 : An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), as mentioned multiple times in your last two or three threads.

Comment: @ildjarn: Apparently my last thread is considered invalid bc i linked rather then copy/pasted code. But anyways I cant provide one as the closes i gotten is above and this needs a proprietory codebase to compile

Comment: The bug is almost certainly in code you haven't shown us, perhaps `String::String`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: String has no constructor (its pod/default ctor with a static_assert to enforce that) and the printf happens before `thefn` is called so its not thefn. I have no idea where the code might be. new could be overloaded but this stack and not using new. So... i cant think of anywhere else it could be

Comment: There's a good chance `valgrind` can figure this out for you. Otherwise, it can't be debugged without the source code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I tried, it reported a write 4 byte error in `thefn` and the address being 0xD which i can see via printfs. Thats the only error as it segfaults there.

Comment: @acidzombie24 : What version of what compiler are you using, and what version of valgrind?

Comment: @ildjarn valgrind-3.7.0, clang 3.0 (above gdb asm), gcc 4.7, under unbuntu 12.04. Windows VC++ compiles and runs it fine though. Also No warnings in clang using -Wall except unused variables.

Comment: @acidzombie24 : valgrind 3.7.x does not support GCC 4.7.x, so it's likely that you're just getting a false-positive from valgrind due to using an unsupported configuration. Update to valgrind 3.8.x (where GCC 4.7.x support was first introduced) and try again.

Comment: @ildjarn: Do you suggest any flags? running with valgrind myapp myargs got me the same error message (it also ends with 1 error in the summary). I instead just compiled with gcc 4.6.3 since i had that installed as well. The error is still write error at address 0xD and i still see D in the printf message

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get a chance to see the end of your previous thread. As I said earlier, can you show some code/disassembly from a caller function?

Comment: @DCoder: I figured it out. You were mostly right about the return value. The assembly is still above. The problem is actually the return value and outside of the function. The compiler seems to use a stack address outside of the frame which explains why the two variables have different address. But the address is significantly different (maybe you can explain why?). The problem is the calling function also returns String and the calling function of that is in C and it did something weird bc it didnt know the return type. Maybe you could explain that but once the C code seen the sig it ran fine

Comment: The reason the `String` object is placed outside the current stack frame is [(Named) Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) that I mentioned earlier. But your problem is of course the fact that the C code "didn't know the return type" - if the compiler doesn't know what data it's really dealing with, nothing good can come from it.

Comment: @DCoder: I didnt realize the C didnt know but from the start i suspected that and the printf were the first things i tried (i still cant believe i was accuses of not getting those results with my build and many request of other functions until i commented them out and ran). But do you have any idea why 0 or D were the address? String is actually a void*ptr but with logic for comparing and such. My C code actually defines it as struct { void*p; } and it runs correctly. So I guess my question to you since you understand this is A) Why was the addr 0xD and

Comment: B) Why does it matter/how is `struct{void*p}` different from simply a void* (all other functions return void* with no issues). The major reason the static_assert exist to force it as POD for C compatibility (i forgot this actually). there is a sizeof assert too making sure int and pointer and the struct all the same size too. Do you have any idea why that broke since to me all logic says it returns a 32bit either way? It probably has to do with RVO

Comment: When *named* RVO is applied, the function's return type changes to `void` - if the caller doesn't know this and expects to find the return value in `eax`, like all normal return values, it will instead read whatever garbage was left in `eax` when the callee finished.

Comment: @DCoder: Oh nice! I didn't know that! That explains a lot. The segfault happens before the return. C is expecting it in EAX, C++ puts it at some address. My question is how does C++ know the address of the named var/val (which in my case is 0xD chosen by the unsuspecting C callee)

Comment: According to (N)RVO, the address of the named var is passed as an additional argument into the function. The C code doesn't do this, so basically the C++ function called from C takes whatever is left at the top of the stack, where the parameter should be ... I think RVO is not applied to functions with C linkage, which you should be doing anyway if you need to interop with C code. (The fact that you're working with C would have been really nice to know back at the beginning of this discussion `:)` )

Comment: @DCoder: I semi forgot there was C. It is generated by a 3rd party util and has more the 15k lines. I don't look there or touch it. I knew i didnt clobber the stack (my C++ doesnt segfaul, crash write invalid places). All I knew it had to do with some kind of optimization and that my stack/code was fine. It also helped i knew to check the stackaddr with &varme. I also knew that r having 0xd as a address is F^*&ed and thats why i showed assembly. It didnt help when ppl accuse my output being false. Nor didnt want to read the assembly even tho tagged and talked about reading the assembly

Comment: @DCoder: If you copy/paste your last comment or two as an answer i'll accept it. Also if you were to look at the source its very C++. There are tons of templates, dynamic checks in there, even C# like properties. Its pretty easy to forget there is C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The setup:

`String` is defined as:

```
struct String {
    void *p;
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    /* Operators to help with comparing, etc. */
    /* No additional data members */
    void thefn(int arg); /* Return/argument type not relevant */
    #endif
};
```

and includes asserts to verify `sizeof(String) == sizeof(void *)` and the struct's POD-ness.

---

*This part was not originally mentioned in the question*: the function that calls this function returns the same `String` object to its caller, but it's called from external C code, where the caller expects a simple `void *` instead of `String`. The author's expectation was that this should work, because the return value's size and layout is the same.

---

### The problem:

The C++ compiler used *[named return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)* (NRVO) in this function. The function signature changed from

```
String fn(char const *);
```

to

```
void fn(char const *, String *);
```

This is visible in the disassembly, where `ebp+0xC` is read from before writing to it, and there's no effort spent on putting meaningful results into [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#32-bit). The `ret 0x4` part was a little strange, since it implies only one argument is cleared off the stack, but apparently that is how GCC/Clang choose to implement this, by having the caller clear off the additional argument.

Presumably, the same optimization was applied in the caller function. But the C compiler saw no reason to apply this optimization (after all, it expected the result to be a `void*`, not a structure) and expected the return value to be passed like any pointer-sized result would be.

As a result:

1. the C code passes only one argument into C++ code, which expects two, and the garbage at the top of the stack gets interpreted as the second argument.
2. The C++ code doesn't produce a meaningful return value where C code expects to find one.

---

### The solution:

The obvious first step towards a fix is to make sure the C code expects the same return value as the C++ code, a struct instead of a pointer.

*However*, I don't think there's a way to control whether NRVO is applied, so I suspect even with the correct return type it's still possible for the two sides of the code to apply this optimization inconsistently, given the small size of the structure. I also have no idea if `extern "C"` would have any effect on it.

(This answer summarizes what was said in the comments, with some guesswork to fill the gaps)

Comment: Because you actually read the assembly, provided me with a hint and because you don't suck I'm giving you 500rep through bounty because thats the max I can set

Comment: @acidzombie24: You do need to actually award the bounty with the button under the tick :)

Comment: @Goz: oh oops lol. I never done this before. I had auto accepted and auto given bounties the 2 times i done it before