# compile with no optimization? as safe as possible?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization, compiler-flags

I have some code acting very weird. Weird enough people accused my output isn't really happening (i wish, that would make my life easier). The code works fine in windows (ms vc++, gcc) but fails on linux (gcc, clang).

I currently compile with `g++ -g -std=c++0x -Wall -c file.cpp` is there anything that is more safe then that? Oh and this segfaults (on linux) even tho there aren't any warnings...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317010/assembly-c-stack-variable-addresses-different-wrong and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316371/why-are-the-stack-addresses-different-wrong .

Answer (score 3):

Seg fault indicates a runtime error such as heap corruption. Whatever the compile option you use, it's not going to help catching all possible run time errors and issues.

i.e. There's no *catch-all-errors* option with *any* set of gcc options.

You can either use a tools such as static analyzer, valgrind or inspect the code where you get the segfault.

Comment: valgrind reports no error until the moment of the segfault, my printfs see the error before the segfault, i showed someone the assembly and they said it looked like a return value optimization error. NO errors/warnings occur on -Wall, it fully works on windows and i am using C++11 features so there may be a few things not worked out. But... there should be something to say disable inlining and other minor optimizations?

Comment: Hard to think compiler optimization would introduce a runtime error. It may affect the performance one positively or negatively but wouldn't introduce errors. Running through GDB & valgrind doesn't catch the segfault?

Comment: it does i used it to figure out why it segfault. It was because of a bad address. The variable is located on the stack. I printed two variables from the stack, one with a normal looking address the other with an invalid address. It blew my mind. If you really are interested and know x86 assembly feel free to look up my last question. But this question is still how do i turn off all optimizations

Comment: Bug was (named) return value optimization. Thats what i wanted to turn off. I just didnt know what it was called

Comment: @acidzombie24: Not exactly a bug considering that behaviour is explicitely allowed by the standard. Might be a better idea to redesign your code to work with that instead of turning it off.

Comment: @Grizzly: Well it was an optimization and it was done in debug mode and i knew some optimization was the problem I just didn't know which. Once I knew I fixed it but before I figured it out it crashed instantly. But now I can probably know by the smell and looking at the stack